# Decoding unknown encoded Traditional Chinese character strings using Python

Tags: python, text-manipulation

Hi I have a website that is in Traditional Chinese and when I check the site statistics it tell me that the search term for the website is `å%8f°å%8d%97 è¦ªå­%90é¤%90å»³` which obviously makes no sense to me. My question is what is this encoding called? And is there a way to use Python to decode this character string. Thank you.

Comment: Encodings are listed here, you can try print "<string".decode(<codec name>)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called a mutt encoding; the underlying bytes have been mangled beyond their original meaning and they are no longer a real encoding.

It was once URL-quoted UTF-8, but now interpreted as latin-1 without unquoting those URL escapes. I was able to un-mangle this by interpreting it as such:

```
>>> from urllib2 import unquote
>>> bytesquoted = u'å%8f°å%8d%97 è¦ªå­%90é¤%90å»³'.encode('latin1')
>>> unquoted = unquote(bytesquoted)
>>> print unquoted.decode('utf8')
台南 親子餐廳
```

Comment: just out of curiosity though why is this particular mutt encoding used on the web statistics site?

Comment: @jih: usually due to inexperience with international character sets and encodings.

Comment: Under python3 the import will be `from urllib.parse import unquote`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet). Install the library with:

```
pip install chardet
# or for python3
pip3 install chardet
```

The library includes a cli utility `chardetect` (or `chardetect3` accordingly) that takes the path to a file.

Once you know the encoding you can use it in python for example like this:

```
codecs.open('myfile.txt', 'r', 'GB2312')
```

or from shell:

```
iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 myfile.txt -o decoded.txt
```

<sup>If you need more performance then there is also **[cchardet](https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet)** — a faster C-optimized version of `chardet`.</sup>