# Python 3.4 decode HEX string

Tags: python, hex, decode, utf8-decode

I'm facing issues to decode the following hex string in python 3.4:

```
b'"\x00\x08\x00\x83\x80\x00\x00\x00\x86\x11\x1dBA\x8c\xdb\xc0\\p\xfe@NR09G06654\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm trying with a simple:

```
data = b'"\x00\x08\x00\x83\x80\x00\x00\x00\x86\x11\x1dBA\x8c\xdb\xc0\\p\xfe@NR09G06654\x00\x00\x00'

print(data.decode('ascii'))
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have also tried to change to UTF-8

```
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

But with no success as the error is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

I have no clue what the problem could be.

Comment: well, what do you expect the character to decode to?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the problem. I am receiving this data from a GPS device and I do not know what the final string is.

Comment: are you even sure it is a string? maybe it is suppose to be a numeric value

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the error means.Since the device is Chinese there might be some strange character in the string

Comment: is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316766/decoding-unknown-encoded-traditional-chinese-character-strings-using-python) related at all? basically `\x83` is invalid character for `utf8` and `ascii` but I think is valid for `latin`

Comment: I'va actually seen this. I am trying to get encoding with chardet and its coming out as windows-1252 ot utf-16be

Comment: It cannot be a single byte encoding system like any of the iso-8859-x, because it contains too much `\x00` characters that are commonly used only for end of string (reminiscence of old ASCIIZ...). Also the `\x08` is back space in all those encodings. It is not utf16-le nor utf32 (neither le nor be). It can be partially decoded as utf-16-be (utf16 big endian) and gives `data.decode('utf-16-be')` -> `'∀ࠀ莀\x00\x86ᄝ䉁賛쁜烾䁎到㥇〶㘵㐀\x00'`. But I cannot imagine what it could mean! I would think more of a frame containing numeric and alpha values...

Comment: First question that comes to mind is what is a "HEX string"? Seriously, you need to first learn what the `b` prefix to a string means and what the backslash sequences mean within that string. Then, find out what the bytes mean in that blob. Finally, check out the Python struct module, which should come handy when trying to decode this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many communication protocols for GPS devices. A lot of devices use NMEA0183, but that is a plain text protocol and this is clearly not plain text.

If you're not running ms-windows, you should check if your GPS is supported by [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/). It translates the signals from the GPS into something understandable. It has Python bindings available.