# How to display Chinese characters correctly in Python?

Tags: python

I read a string containing Chinese characters and it displays as "❤12💳✈"

How to display the string correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: It is part python and part the editor you are using. First try using something like IDLE instead of your terminal. Then you will want to ensure you are using the correct code-page (likely Big5 Chinese) Unicode instead of the default byte string.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316766/decoding-unknown-encoded-traditional-chinese-character-strings-using-python you should precise an enconding using the library urllib2

Comment: Could you also show the original character

Answer (score 0):

It is part Python and part the editor/terminal you are using. First try using something like IDLE instead of your terminal. Then you will want to ensure you are using the correct code-page (likely Big5 Chinese) Unicode instead of the default byte string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import html

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

a = 'your string'

print(html.unescape(a).translate(non_bmp_map))
```